# any way to execute batch file in subeclipse commit click

Tags: eclipse, svn, hook

I(developer) am using project in eclipse IDE using Subeclipse and the SVN server is on our server machine. Is there any way to execute batch file in client side where developer is, when he tries to commit through subeclipse.... I need to get some information from client side to SVN server to log in our database through pre-commit or post-commit hook script..

Thanks in advance..

Comment: what kind of data do you need from the client?